# Checking if my input box has been click or is 'in focus' pure js

Tags: javascript

I need to know if my input box is clicked so I can fire a script to do something, except none of the routes I'm attempting seem to do anything.

basic input box

```
<input type="text" id="search-stuff" placeholder="search"/>
```

Javascript

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("search-stuff");
if (inputBox) {
    inputBox.addEventListener('keyup',function () {
        startSearch();
    })
    inputBox.addEventListener('onfocus',function() {
        console.log('we clicked');
        searchBoxClicked();
    })
}

function searchBoxClicked() { console.log('we clicked it'); }
```

I need to know if the user clicks so I can clear some classes on previous elements before the user types something.

Comment: What's `form` ?

Comment: `form.addEventListener('onfocus'` would be listening for the event `ononfocus`

Comment: You should be listening to `input`

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a mistake when I was copying it over to stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it right. A few minor mistakes:

1. to listen to the `focus` event. `onfocus` isn't an event.
2. the `keyup` event is for listening when a keyboard button is released (following a `keydown` event). If you want to listen to a mouse click, use the `click` event.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById("search-stuff");
if (inputBox) {
  inputBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
    startSearch();
  });
  inputBox.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    searchBoxClicked();
  });
}

function searchBoxClicked() {
  console.log('focus');
}

function startSearch() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-stuff" placeholder="search" />
```

Comment: The keyup event is actually a separate function altogether (nothing to do with the onfocus, or should I say focus event. 

The solution for changing 'onfocus' to 'focus' actually solved my problem. I got it to work!

Comment: @RobertOchinski great!

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event listener to your input instead of the form. Instead of getElementById you could iterate the children to find it or use a selector.
When using event listeners the event is `click` or `focus` not `onclick` or `onfocus`.

```
document.getElementById('search-stuff').addEventListener('focus',function() {
    console.log('clicked it');
};
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#formName > input[type=text]').addEventListener('focus',function() {
    console.log('clicked it');
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('#formName > input[type=text]')
.addEventListener('focus',function() {
        console.log('clicked on ' + this.name);
    });
```

```html
<form id="formName">
  <input name="username" type="text" value="press here">
</form>
```

Comment: my one event listener in my example that triggers on 'keyup' does work, but when I add the second event listener for 'onfocus' it does not. I've also attempted to separate the two event listeners to see if that caused the issue. Is this because onfocus need's a form wrapper?